# Does webpack always bundle the whole module file?

Tags: webpack

I am new to webpack and I am playing around with it.

Right now I use a very simple configuration file:

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: 'app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  }
};
```

When I try to compare the entry and output files, I realize that no matter I import the whole module `import WholeModule from './module';` or just some of the functions of it `import { doSth } from './module';` in `app.js`, webpack always bundle the whole module file into the output file.

Is there any webpack configuration I can set to make it bundle only the functions used by other files?

Comment: What you're thinking of is [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and requires use of ES6 syntax throughout.